# search for a folder structure and copy to another folder in windows OS

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am looking for a Windows batch file script to search for a particular named and copy it to another folder as a sub directory.

I tried to copy all the sub-directories ending with service/test.txt to another directory using the xcopy command with complete directory name as below:

```
xcopy .\alpha1\beta1\service\test .\copydir
xcopy .\alpha1\beta2\service\test .\copydir
```

However, I have many file structures to go through and copy. So, I am wondering if there is a script or command I could use to copy these files.

Comment: Windows *or* DOS? The command-line interface in Microsoft Windows has nothing to do with the ancient MS‑DOS operating system.

Comment: I think this is a very similar question to this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609028/copying-files-with-wildcards-in-the-path][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609028/copying-files-with-wildcards-in-the-path

Comment: Hi, you are correct. it is something similar to above thread. Here are the details.
 I have below folder structures:

/configs/abc1/server1/service/test.txt /configs/abc1/server1/website/test.txt /configs/abc2/service/test.txt 
/configs/abc2/website/test.txt 
.... 
.... 
/configs/abc30/server1/service/test.txt /configs/abc30/server1/website/test.txt 

From the above folder structures, I would like to copy all the subdirectories with names "service/test.txt" starting with /config/ subfolder name to another folder.Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
MD %destdir% 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /s /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*"^|findstr /l /i /e "\service\test" '
 ) DO (
 SET "target=%%a"
 CALL SET target=%%target:%sourcedir%=%destdir%%%
 CALL md "%%target%%\" 2>nul
 CALL XCOPY /s /e /v "%%a" "%%target%%\" >nul
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should get the task finished.

It looks at the directory tree, picking out all directorynames (`dir../ad`) and filters those that end "\service\test" (`findstr../e..`)

Then it assigns the source name to `target`, replaces the source name with the destination name, creates the new destination name, suppressing `'already exists'` messages and copies the source contents to the (new) directory.

Comment: Hi all, I found the following solution:

echo \Mors\ > Mors.txt

xcopy /s /f /r /y /EXCLUDE:Mors.txt .\configs .\CopyTo

Echo command creates a .txt file with folder name that needs to be excluded.