# Copy a file from network share system cannot find path specified

Tags: batch-file, copy, login-script, network-share

I have a seriously weird problem, and I suspect it has something to do with the length of the filename - but I cannot alter it (for now).

I'm trying to copy a file from a network share to the users local %temp% with a logon script. The reason for this, is that each user needs to have an individual copy of the file when opening it so that the next users doesn't get a "file is locked" message.

If I run the command manually in a CMD window, the file gets copied, but if I place it in a login.bat-file on the domains netlogon-folder and tries to run the bat-file, I get "The system cannot find the path specified."

This is the actually command:

```
COPY /Y "\\SERVER\Felles\Administrasjon\Customer KS-manual\Kvalitetshåndbok\2000 org. kart\2 0 B 01-14 Customer Name Arbeids-Prosess-flyt_NO.odg" %TEMP%\Kvalitetshaandbok.odg
```

So as I said - if I type that in CMD, the file gets copied. If I place it in \customer.local\NETLOGON\login.bat and run the BAT-file, I get "The system cannot find the path specified."
I also tried earlier to just open the file, and that only worked if I opened \customer.local\NETLOGON\shortcut.lnk and shortcut.lnk pointed to the UNC-path of the file. The problem is that I cannot copy a file using a shortcut.lnk AFAIK.

My main object is to have each user get a unique copy of the file and opened on logon.
Is the problem isolated to the length, or is there something else I miss out on?

Comment: Maybe this question is better off on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) since it's not really related to programming.

Comment: I have narrowed down the error to the norwegian letter "å" in "Kvalitetshåndbok"-folder. If that isn't present the file copies just fine - but i've also altered from login.bat to login.cmd ... Still haven't figured it all out.
Tried doing XCOPY and COPY with Kvalitetsh*bok as part of the filename and now it cannot find the file.

The latter part you mention is placed in the back of my head when I finally can get the file copied but not running (if that will happen).

Answer (score 0):

Try `"%TEMP%\Kvalitetshaandbok.odg"` with the double quotes because the username can contain spaces etc, which trickles down to the `%temp%` path.

There are also non-latin characters in the path and the code page being used may need to be altered to match the character set.

Comment: Yeah, I've narrowed it down to the non-latin character. Trying various uses of wildcard now to get the file copied. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Yes! Found a solution!

Comment: PUSHD "\\SERVER\Felles\Administrasjon\Customer KS-manual\Kvalitets*\2000 org. kart"
XCOPY /Y "2 0 B 01-14 Customer Name Arbeids-Prosess-flyt_NO.odg" %TEMP%\Kvalitetshaandbok.odg
START %TEMP%\Kvalitetshaandbok.odg

All thanks to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609028/copying-files-with-wildcards-in-the-path