# Windows 7 commands- copy a file with a specific Name from a folder with dynamic folder name

Tags: command

```
C:\Automateinstaller\@*.*\cucumber-junitreport.xml C:\destin /Y /H /E /F /I
```

I am using above command but not able to copy the `cucumber-junitreport.xml` file to "`destin`" folder can anyone help me with this

Here the folder with dynamic name always with `@` in its name

Comment: C:\Automateinstaller\@*.*\cucumber-junitreport.xml C:\destin /Y /H /E /F /I this is the command i am using

Comment: are you generating this copy command from your code or how?

Comment: You have the answer as why it can not work here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609028/copying-files-with-wildcards-in-the-path . But if you use two lines, it can be done.